# Realizar formato imprimible desde JAVA 8

Tags: java

PREGUNTA EDITADA.

Y logre realizar los que requiero, el error como me comentaban en la pregunta anterior que realice era en la librerias, cosa que ya corregí y también elimine las lineas del uuid para otro error que me salía, ahora el detalle que tengo es que me arroja el reporte no tiene paginas, ya no me da error pero lanza reporte sin páginas, adjunto mi codigo de como llamo al reporte.

Codigo para llamar al reporte con parametros y sin conexion de datos.

```
private void BTImprimirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

    try{

  HashMap parametro = new HashMap();
  parametro.put("paciente",TFPaciente.getText());
  parametro.put("indicaciones", TAConsulta.getText());

  JasperReport reporte = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("C:\\Users\\Saul\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\GinecologiaHEG\\src\\ginecologiaheg\\RecetaReporte.jrxml");    

  JasperPrint jasperPrint  = JasperFillManager.fillReport(reporte,parametro);
  JasperViewer view =  new JasperViewer(jasperPrint,false);
  view.setVisible(true);
} catch(Exception ex){
    System.out.println("Error: "+ex);
}

}
```

Cabe mencionar que dentro del reporte manejo 2 parametros que es lo unico que deseo pasar, en si es una Receta medica donde le paso el nombre del paciente y las indicaciones y listo, sin Conexion ni nada.

Parametros: paciente e indicaciones.

Saludos y de antemano gracias.

Comment: Hola Saul Moreno Madrigal. Como has dicho, con JasperReports puedes conseguir lo que quieres. Por favor, edita la pregunta añadiendo el código que te fallaba indicando donde para poder ayudarte. Puedes mirar [ask] para que veas como reformular tu pregunta.

Comment: Ya edite la pretunta.

Comment: Para comentar que ya resolvi el problema, era simplemente agregar en el en el FileReport el JREmptyDataOSource() y con eso fue suficiente, ahora si ya mearroja el reporte con datos.